# how to make that my code can detect every link I want

Tags: reactjs

So I want my react code to detect every link like I type for example "http://localhost:3000/"
it gives me a formatted link and not a plain text

here is my code:

```
//Linkify.jsx
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'
const Linkify = ({ children }) => {
  const isUrl = (word) => {
    const urlPattern = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/gm;
    return word.match(urlPattern);
  };

  const addMarkup = (word) => {
    return isUrl(word) ? `<a class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600 transition" href="${word}">${word}</a>` : `<span className="no-underline">${word}</span>`;
  };

  const words = children.split(" ");
  const formatedWords = words.map((w, i) => addMarkup(w));

  const html = DOMPurify.sanitize(formatedWords.join(' '))

  return <span  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
};

export default Linkify;
```

```
import Linkify from "./Linkify"

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Linkify>
      http://localhost:3000/
      </Linkify>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
//this code gives me not a link but a plain text
```

Anything helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated your code in codepen and it works fine, just the port on the URL and not having a top-level domain (TLD) which the RegEx is not picking up.

Using your code with a regularly formatted URL works fine.

[Working Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/huzi8t9/pen/BaMRbqa)

```
import dompurify from "https://esm.sh/dompurify";
import React from "https://esm.sh/react";
import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom";

const Linkify = ({ children }) => {
  const isUrl = (word) => {
    const urlPattern = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/gm;
    return word.match(urlPattern);
  };

  const addMarkup = (word) => {
    return isUrl(word)
      ? `<a class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600 transition" href="${word}">${word}</a>`
      : `<span className="no-underline">${word}</span>`;
  };

  const words = children.split(" ");
  const formatedWords = words.map((w, i) => addMarkup(w));

  const html = dompurify.sanitize(formatedWords.join(" "));

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
};

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Linkify>
        Add a URL in here, for example, http://www.google.com/ -- look's good!
      </Linkify>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));

root.render(<Test />);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I found answer on my problem,here is the code for detecting every link:

```
import dompurify from "dompurify";


// detects every link now
const Linkify = ({ children }) => {
  const isUrl = (word) => {
    const urlPattern = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return word.match(urlPattern);
  };

  const addMarkup = (word) => {
    return isUrl(word)
      ? `<a class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600 transition" href="${word}">${word}</a>`
      : `<span className="no-underline text-white">${word}</span>`;
  };

  const words = children.split(" ");
  const formatedWords = words.map((w, i) => addMarkup(w));

  const html = dompurify.sanitize(formatedWords.join(" "));

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
};

export default Linkify
```